# Searching a .json file and displaying with Discord.js

Tags: json, discord.js

What I am trying to is:

User does !check (id)

The bot will search a json file

```
[
    {
        "name": “adam”,
        "age": “16”,
        "id": "9"
    },
    {
        "name": “jack”,
        "age": “18”,
        "id": "10"
    }

]
```

Example:
!check 9

The bot will then reply with

```
name: adam
age:16
id:9
```

How can ı do that?

Comment: That JSON file is not valid JSON

Comment: I fixed, so can you explain what ı asked thank you for your information

Answer (score 1):

You can first import the JSON file by using require, filter through them to find out the entry having the specific ID you want and then respond to the interaction. A simplified version would look something like this:

```js
// For demo purposes, I have added the JSON object directly in the code.
// But in your code, you can just do something like this: 
// const entries = require("./filepath/to/json/file")
const entries = [{
    "name": "adam",
    "age": "16",
    "id": 9
  },
  {
    "name": "jack",
    "age": "18",
    "id": 10
  }
]

const objId = 9

const filteredObj = entries.filter((obj) => obj.id === objId)[0]
const name = filteredObj.name
const age = filteredObj.age
const id = filteredObj.id

console.log("Name: ", name)
console.log("Age: ", age)
console.log("Id: ", id)
```

Comment: This is helped me a lot but how can ı adaptation to discord bot

Comment: For capturing user input, you can use [slash commands](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/slash-commands.html#before-you-continue) and add [options](https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/parsing-options.html) to them

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please accept it as the correct solution!